# socket.sendto failing to send the data in pyyhon

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following code in python to send data to another port using socket

```
gs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM,0)
gs.sendto("datatest",(ip,port))
gs.close()
```

However, I'm not able to receive the data from client side. What could be the reason the data is not being sent to that particular ip and port. I have added a print statement after `gs.close()` to confirm if the sendto command is executed and I confirmed that the command was executed. There is no error too.

I tried debugging using print statement and checking for errors and also by checking from client side.

Comment: it is being sent to that ip,port combo ... 100% guaranteed ... you are probably trying to send it somewhere other than localhost ... chances are there is not a server at that address/port

Comment: What does your receiver code look like?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I don't have access to the receiver code. but the receiver confirmed it saying we are not able to see the data

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I observed one thing that, when a sendto command is executed, it prints out the number of bytes/ or some data. But from my side, it doesn't prints anything. I thought there might be an issue while sending

Comment: you are not sending to the correct ip/port ... or it is not supposed to be udp ... or any other number of issues ... but it is definitely sending your bytes to the specified ip/port  ... without knowing more no one can help you ... you at least need to send bytes (`b"payload"`) or you get an error (at least in python3) .returns nuymber of bytes sent ... it doesnt print them .. try `print(sock.sendto(...))` and you should see the size of payload printed ... even if the ip/port doesnt exist ... UDP doesnt care if it exists or not ... nor whether it actually is delivered/has path to target

Comment: `sendto` doesn't print anything.  It RETURNS something, so if you say `print(gs.sendto(...))`, you could see the numbers.  Are you absolutely sure you're supposed to send UDP, and not TCP?  Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I got cleared in the returning part of `sendto` part. When I printed, the sendto command, it printed 48. I'm using python 2. What changes should be made if we need to send it to UDP and not TCP